# Converting MS SQL Date to JavaScript full datetime adds 3 hours

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have date type column in MS SQL table, which I need to convert to full date and time in JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/dates",
                data: {},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    holidays = new Array();
                    for (var i of data[0])
                    {
                        date = new Date(i.holiday_date);
                        console.log(date);
                        holidays.push(date);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The result is:

Mon May 01 2017 **03:00:00** GMT+0300 (FLE Summer Time)

Tue May 02 2017 **03:00:00** GMT+0300 (FLE Summer Time)

My question is why it is adding three hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably passing an ISO 8601 date `YYYY-MM-DD` to the Date object, and those are treated as UTC time. Thus, when converted to local time, 3 hours are added. The same would happen if you're passing unix timestamps.

Now, you shouldn't just add or remove 3 hours somewhere to correct for it, since it will break twice a year with daylight savings time.

The best way would be to either use a full ISO 8601 timestamp `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, e.g. `2017-05-02T00:00:00+03:00`, or use separate parameters for the Date object constructor because in that case those are treated as local time, not UTC:

```
new Date(year, month, day);
```

More about Date objects here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

As far as I can find, you can get a full ISO 8601 timestamp out of SQL Server like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 127)
```

Answer (score 1):

because the result date is not in your time zone, take at look the date format `Mon May 01 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Summer Time)` ,`GMT+0300`means add three hours.